# How to take Data from a div and put it into a JS array

Tags: javascript

html:

```
<div id="array"></div>
```

App 1: inserts data into a html div

```
 document.getElementById('array').innerText = data;
```

App 2: takes data from html

```
 let new_data = document.getElementById('array').innerText
```

Is it possible to turn new_data into an array and if so how?

Comment: If you need more code let me know and I can post more, it just might be a bit of a jumbled mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply take a storage variable and push the values from the div into it.

A simple example, which you probably still have to adjust.

```js
const storage = []
document.getElementById('array').innerText = 'Hello';
storage.push( document.getElementById('array').innerText )


let newData = document.getElementById('array').innerText = document.getElementById('array').innerText + ' World';
storage.push(newData)
console.log(storage)
```

```html
<div id="array"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

with new_data, you can use .innerText/.textContent/.innerHTML, whichever works to your liking to get the content inside, and then, since it is a string, you can just use .split() if you wish to split it.
If the content is a JSON object, you can use JSON.parse(the_string_here) to get a JSON object / Array from a string into the respective object.

If that doesn't help, could you share what the content of the html div looks like, so I could get a better understanding of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: That was exactly what I needed to do, not sure why using .split() wasn't something I already tried. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, happy to help